# Methods for analyzing Red Hat sosreport output?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, configuration, diagnostic

For some time (since EL 4.6), Red Hat has embedded a [system report and troubleshooting tool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/3592&ei=2QBiULXaE7PlyAHgnYCADA&usg=AFQjCNHKlIrg1XXnMaPiH4LvgF9kfZzvkg) into the operating system. The tool, [sosreport](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/3592&ei=2QBiULXaE7PlyAHgnYCADA&usg=AFQjCNHKlIrg1XXnMaPiH4LvgF9kfZzvkg), collects system information and settings and bundles it into a tar.bz archive for easy distribution. Normally, this is intended for Red Hat support, but can prove to be a useful diagnostic in other situations.

*Note - This tool is also installed on CentOS and other Red Hat derivatives.*

I'm curious if there are any useful methods to compare the `sosreport` output from two different systems. I'm chasing down a bug that affects one server, while there's no impact on another "identical" system. It seems as though there should be a way to "diff" the `sosreport` output to see what configuration differences exist between the two platforms.

Any particular tips or creative uses of the `sosreport` framework in your systems environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try  sxconsole.

"sxconsole is a tool used to extract various report types and then
analyze those extracted reports with plug-ins. The tool also provides
an archiving structure so that all the compressed and extracted
reports are saved to a directory. This tool was developed for
sysreport/sosreports but has been expanded to include any report that
has a class defined."

- https://github.com/sbradley7777/sx

Answer (score 3):

Try saj (former sosreport-analyzer-ng).

https://github.com/intrajp/saj

You can deploy many files into one .txt file, so, you can diff two sosreports.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

There is a package called checksysreport which can be used to extract information and see which bugs are fixed in which update but that is hardly a utility to do diff. Also, I guess that package is internal only but I am not sure. I can check if you want.

Comment: Definitely. I'm interested in seeing how/if people use sosreport in their environments, or if it's just a method of shipping system info back to Red Hat...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to `diff` a sosreports contents would be to use `meld` (a GUI-based diff).  More info here: http://meldmerge.org/

You can extract two sosreports and then `meld` the directories:

```
 # meld <sosreport-1 dir> <sosreport-2 dir>
```

Comment: I tried that. It's a bit messy and slow given the complexity of the directories... Especially since Meld is an X11 application.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled across another tool called `xsos` which can also analyze the contents of a `sosreport` output payload.

```
[rsaw]$ xsos aczx998pinkle/
OS
  Hostname: aczx998pinkle
  Distro:   [redhat-release] Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Carthage)
            [enterprise-release] Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Carthage)
  RHN:      serverURL=https://linux-update.oracle.com/XMLRPC
  Runlevel: N 3  (default 3)
  SELinux:  permissive  (default enforcing)
  Arch:     mach=x86_64  cpu=x86_64  platform=x86_64
  Kernel:
    Booted kernel:  2.6.18-238.12.2.0.2.el5
    GRUB default:   2.6.18-238.12.2.0.2.el5
    Build version:
      Linux version 2.6.18-238.12.2.0.2.el5 (mockbuild@ca-build9.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.1.2
      20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)) #1 SMP Tue Jun 28 05:21:19 EDT 2011
    Booted kernel cmdline:
      root=/dev/md6 ro bootarea=c0d0 loglevel=7 panic=60 debug rhgb numa=off console=ttyS0,115200n8
      console=tty1 crashkernel=128M@16M bootfrom=CELLBOOT audit=1 processor.max_cstate=1 nomce
    GRUB default kernel cmdline:
      root=/dev/md6 ro bootarea=c0d0 loglevel=7 panic=60 debug rhgb numa=off console=ttyS0,115200n8
      console=tty1 crashkernel=128M@16M bootfrom=BOOT audit=1 processor.max_cstate=1 nomce
    Kernel taint-check: 536870912 512 64 16 1
      Technology Preview code is loaded
      Taint on warning
      Userspace-defined naughtiness
      System experienced a machine check exception
      Proprietary module has been loaded
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  Sys time:  Mon Oct 29 10:55:02 CDT 2012
  Boot time: Sat Apr 28 03:29:56 CDT 2012  (1335583796)
  Uptime:    184 days, 12:25,  1 user
  LoadAvg:   [24 CPU] 2.34 (10%), 1.27 (5%), 0.95 (4%)
  /proc/stat:
    procs_running: 4    procs_blocked: 1    processes: 248052571
    cpu:  [Break-down of CPU time since boot]
      us 1%, ni 0%, sys 1%, idle 96%, iowait 2%, irq 0%, sftirq 0%, steal 0%
```

Similar example, `xsos -om` -or- `xsos --os --mem`, showing off color output:

[image]

#### References

- https://github.com/ryran/xsos
- https://access.redhat.com/discussions/469323